# C# Regex for splitting a string into Parameter Item

Tags: c#-3.0

How can I split a string using regex to obtain a result as follow:

```
input = "@IDNumber==123;@Title==\"Tool Designer\";@HireDate==\"1999-03-30\";@UKCode==\"IX-IHNR\";@UKCAT==\"BR=XXX==YYYY\";@CountryCode==\" \";@AdvisorCode==655;@AdvisorXX==\"\"";
```

The result I'd like to have is:

---

```
1) @IDNumber==123;

2) @Title=="Tool Designer"

3) @HireDate=="1999-03-30"

4) @UKCode=="IX-IHNR"

5) @UKCAT=="BR=XXX==YYYY"

6) @CountryCode==" "

7) @AdvisorCode==655

8) @AdvisorXX==""
```

---

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex - use `String.Split` like this:

```
using System;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String input = "@IDNumber==123;@Title==\"Tool Designer\";@HireDate==\"1999-03-30\";@UKCode==\"IX-IHNR\";@UKCAT==\"BR=XXX==YYYY\";@CountryCode==\" \";@AdvisorCode==655;@AdvisorXX==\"\"";

        foreach (String s in input.Split(';'))
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but what happens if there's a ; inside a string?

Comment: I agree with the approach and appreciate the possibility that a ";" would show up, but I'm much more inclined to think this is much simpler (and conveys the intent) than a regex.

Comment: In this case you may split by ";@"

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

```
input.Split(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is regex:

```
@NAME==(.*?);?(@|$)
```

when matching replace NAME with your param name and get the value of the second the group:

```
var value = Regex.Match(input, "@IDNumber==(.*?);?(@|$)").Groups[1].Value;
```